# Dialog Slide Down Animation overlaps native android buttons bar layout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialogfragment, slidedown

As the question title conveys, I am trying to close a dialog with slide down animation. Everything works perfectly except that while sliding down, the whole dialog layout overlaps the native android buttons bar (**Check the attached screenshot**).

This issue doesn't happen when opening the dialog. The slide up animation happens perfectly, and does so from behind of the native buttons bar (which is the desired behavior...again **screenshot attached**).

How to go about fixing this?

Below are the xml animations I'm using

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"/>
</set>
```

**slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"/>
</set>
```

**Slide Down Screen Shot**
[image: Dialog Slide Down]

**Slide Up Screen Shot**
[image: Dialog Slide Up]

Comment: hey did you ever solve this? I'm stuck with that problem too

Comment: no @T.Vert didn't solve it. Actually the requirement itself was scrapped so didn't dig further. Sorry for such a late reply